# Yet another div height question

Tags: html, css

Over the years, I've struggled with this.  This year, there might be a solution.
I need a header, content and footer.
I would like the footer to be at the bottom of the page, the header at the top, and the content in between.

I would like the content to have a scroll bar.

Q: Is that too much to ask?

Comment: You want the header/footer/content to occupy 100% / 100% of the browser's windows, and having the content area with scrolling capabilities ? If soo, I can send an example... if not, rephrase :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A: No.**

CSS:

```
#content {
  height: XXXpx;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: Ah.  My whole problem was that I was using overflow-y: visible; instead of auto;

Answer (score 4):

If the header and footer have fixed heights:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #header {
        height: 100px;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        background-color: red;
    }
    #footer {
        height: 100px;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        background-color: green;
    }
    #content {
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 100px;
        bottom: 100px;
        overflow: auto;
        background-color: blue;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely sure whether this really answers your question but the property for getting a scroll bar if necessary (i.e. if a container's content exceeds its size) is

```
overflow: auto
```

there are selective properties for horizontal and vertical scroll bars:

```
overflow-x: auto;
overflow-y: auto;
```

but they are part of the CSS 3.0 specification and only supported by a limited number of browsers (namely Firefox > 1.5, Opera and Safari).

Comment: I thought it was `overflow:scroll;`

Comment: @Aren `auto` will show a scroll bar when necessary; `scroll` will always show a scroll bar.

Answer (score 2):

This give you a fixed header and footer of height 50 px, and a content area that is scrollable.

```
<html>
<body>
  <div id="header" style="position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px; height: 50px; overflow:hidden">
  </div>
  <div id="content" style="position:absolute; left:0px; top:50px; bottom:50px; overflow:auto;">
  </div>
  <div id="footer" style="position:absolute; left:0px; bottom:0px; height:50px; overflow:hidden;">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want just the content to scroll, you can have a fixed header and footer. That's the only way I know of. Check out this link for implementation hints:

http://www.pmob.co.uk/temp/fixedlayoutexample5.htm